# Status of Install Ubuntu on May 2019 Macbook Pro (with touchbar)

Tags: drivers, macbook

(highlevel: not a ticket of how-to, but a ticket of how-to-track-status)

Hi, is it true that this is not yet possible? Based on some other questions, it seems that there may not be drivers yet for the SSD controller. This seems plausible since every attempt i've made the live CD has not been able to "see" the hard drive at all.

Is there an "edge" branch somewhere I could try, or are these drivers still completely unavailable? Is there somewhere I can track progress of this? (a github issue maybe)

Comment: It has nothing to do with drivers, nor with GNU/Linux whatsoever. It's that Macbooks since 2018 has some "security chip" embedded, which artificially reduces possible usecases for the Macbook. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471124/59928#how-can-you-get-any-version-of-linux-to-see-the-2018-macbook-pro-ssd) for details.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for replying. I definitely misread that post. Is this similar to LV0 keys on the PS3, where there are special cryptographic keys that would allow access (that Apple shared only with Microsoft)

Comment: Mmm… I think, no. This situation does not seem to involve a cryptography *(at least not further than detecting Windows 10)*. Basically, this chip disallows to any OS that's being installed through UEFI to see the SSD. It *maybe* allows it to be seen by anything that's installed through Boot Camp software, but latest Boot Camp only supports Windows 10. As a result, to SSD you only can install Windows 10 *(not even 7 or 8)*, and only through Boot Camp.

Comment: Well, [breaking news, from 4 hours ago, just for you](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MacBook-Finally-Linux-SSD-RW) ☺ Apparently, the linked answer on unix.stackexchange isn't entirely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today Ubuntu 19.10 does not work on Macbook Pro 2019.
I tried to boot from live flash drive.
The problems was that touchpad and keyboard was not functional.

Also after connecting usb mouse i figured out that WiFi and HardDrive also lack driver support.

Comment: That's not good news... I just think about installing Ubuntu to my MacBook Pro 2019 today, it seems it's not a good idea...